# Print lines with JUST grep on a string and nothing more?

Tags: bash

Using grep, can I search for something in a file and just get the lines which contain the string and not additional lines which contain other text?  In the example below (as a simplification) I want to print  the lines with password =  and not password = [:alnum:]. I am not sure how to do this. I kind of need grep because I am actually capturing more than just this line but I am excluding this larger command from my question.

File with data:

```
    password = Mike
    password = Jessica
    password = 
    password = Sofi
    password = Maya
    password =
```

Prints:

```
    password = 
    password =
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$` (end of line) to make sure there's no additional text:

```
grep '^password =\s*$' file
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. `grep '^password =\s*$' file`

Comment: this seems to be working for me:  egrep 'password =\s*$' -B 1  -A 2 ./test

Comment: the ^ carrot doesn't seem to help

Comment: @MikeQ `-B` and `-A` will get the lines before and after the match. You didn't mention you want anything like this in the question, further, your "expected output" doesn't reflect such a requirement.

Comment: The ^ matches start of line. Useful if you want to gaurd against matching ' password = ', where there is empty space at beginning if line.

Comment: @MikeQ as for the caret: if you have lines in which there are spaces/tabs/whatever before `password` (and you still want to match these lines) then yes, remove the caret.

Comment: I think that you mean caret! :^)

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -F -x 'password =' file
```

The `-F` is a minor tweak to disable regex matching and only match literal strings. The `-x` specifies that the entire line must match.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Fast (because of no regex handling), short, and [POSIX compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) to boot.

Comment: It depends on whether the input line contains any spaces before or after the `password = `. If it does, this doesn't work (for obvious reasons :)

Comment: Oh, right, the search expression must have exactly the same spacing as the lines you want to match. If they can vary, maybe use a regex after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression with egrep and invert the match with `-v`:

```
grep -E -v 'password = \S+' file
```

Comment: the  S needs to be lower case

Comment: @Mike Q, match is inverted using `-v` option.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep with extended regular expressions (note that `egrep` is deprecated):

```
grep -E '=\s*$' file
```

This ensures that after the equals sign, there is only whitespace before the end of the line.

Alternatively, assuming that they're all space characters (no tabs, for example):

```
grep '= *$' file
```

You could also use the POSIX whitespace character class:

```
grep '=[[:space:]]*$' file
```

If you need to also ensure that the word "password" is on the line as well:

```
grep -E 'password\s*=\s*$' file
```

Comment: Tom, thanks for responding, do you know why I can't use these with Awk ?   for example this doesn't work for me:  awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/password =\s*$/' ./test

Comment: "\s" isn't understood by awk. Depending on your version of awk and content of your file, you should do something like `awk '/password = *$/' file` or `awk '/password =[[:space:]]*$/' file`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah , those work.  but when I add the RS= and ORS= it all falls apart!

Comment: What should the record separator be? If you edit your question to make it clearer exactly what you're trying to do, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433338/capturing-range-of-lines-with-awk-wild-posix-cards-not-working

Comment: @Mike OK I'll take a look when I get a chance. This question was about grep and you've been provided some useful answers, so you should upvote the ones that have been helpful and accept your favourite. Thanks.