# Capturing range of lines with awk, multiline records not working

Tags: awk

I am trying to understand why I can't use awk when invoking the RS= and ORS= options. Is there a better way to do this?

This works:

```
    awk '/password =[[:space:]]*$/' ./test
    awk '/password =  *$/' ./test
```

But I need this to work:

```
    awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/password = *$/' ./test
```

Sample file (./test) :

```
    User_Mike1:
           password = 12345678
           somedata = whatever

    User_Mike2:
           password = 12345678
           somedata = whatever

    User_Mike3:
           password = 
           somedata = whatever

    User_Mike4:
           password = 12345678
           somedata = whatever
```

Desired output (the record containing 'password =' i.e. an empty password entry):

```
    User_Mike3:
           password = 
           somedata = whatever
```

I also need the lines with password =* or password = * as well. Scratching my head over this one!

EDIT: ANSWER

I think my problem was with the file itself, I added new lines manually and the script worked correctly..

In my case I want the records with  password =* password = * password =  or login = false:

```
    awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n' '/password = [*]/ || /password =[*]/ || /login = false/ || /password = \n/'
```

Comment: The actual file didn't have the newlines that your sample snippet had?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `RS=` newline isn't the end of your record anymore. So your `$` in the pattern is failing to match what you expect.

Try `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/password = *\n/' ./test`

Or to keep using `$` try: `awk -v FS='\n' -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$2 ~ /= *$/' ./test`

Comment: +1 It's a common misconception that `$` means `end of line`. It doesn't, it means `end of string`. I think that's the conceptual problem the OP had. It just so happens that tools like `sed`, `grep`, and `awk` (with default RS) separate their input into strings to be processed one line at a time so in that situation `end of string`, `end of record`, and `end of the line` are all the same thing, `$`. It's when you do NOT use the default RS in awk that the difference becomes evident. `$` still means `end of string` and `end of record` but now that's NOT the same as `end of line` which is `\n`.

Comment: awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n' '/password = [*]/ || /password =[*]/ || /login = false/ || /password = \n/'  worked for me ... I think the issue was with the newlines which I added to the file manually.

Comment: `'/password =(| ?\*| *)\n/'` might do what you need for all the password lines.

Answer (score 0):

The next perl

```
perl -00 -lanE 'say "$_\n" if m/password\s*=\s*\*?\s*\n/' <<EOF
    User_Mike1:
           password = 12345678
           somedata = whatever

    User_Mike2:
           password = *
           somedata = whatever

    User_Mike3:
           password = 
           somedata = whatever

    User_Mike4:
           password = 12345678
           somedata = whatever
EOF
```

prints

```
    User_Mike2:
           password = *
           somedata = whatever

    User_Mike3:
           password = 
           somedata = whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I didn't want to start adding in perl but I was close to doing it. Thanks again.